# Sequence defined $f_n = \frac{a}{1+f_{n-1}}$ is convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Sequence $<f_n>$ defined by $f_n = \frac{a}{1+f_{n-1}}$ where $f_1$ and $a$ are positive.
Is this sequence monotonic ?
I only know, If this sequence is convergent, then it's limit will be the positive root of $x^2 + x = a$. Is is possible to exploit this fact to prove that it is convergent.

Comment: From the *potential* limit doesn't follow anything, unfortunately, and "helpful" assurances ("we can deduce") you've had, already. Do you want an explicit expression for $f_n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire sequence is not monotonic but the odd terms and even terms form monotonic subsequences.
$f_n-f_{n-2} = \frac{-a(f_{n-1} - f_{n-3})}{(1+f_{n-1})({1+f_{n-3}})} = \frac{a^2(f_{n-2} - f_{n-4})}{(1+f_{n-1})({1+f_{n-3}})(1+f_{n-2})(1+f_{n-4})}$ Thus if n is  odd then , the terms of odd subsequences are monotonic (i.e 1, 3, 5,7...) and if n is even, then even terms are monotonic. Also, from the first equality, if odd terms are monotonically increasing, then even terms are monotonically decreasing and vice - versa. Further, the odd and even terms converge to the same limit. It is easy to prove this using the equation $f_n = \frac{a}{1+f_{n-1}}$. The sequence $<f_n>$ is bounded below by $0$ and above by $a$. We can deduce this from the  definition of ${f_n}$